# What's this thing (air gap?) in my hotel's bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, pipe

I found this thing in my hotel bathroom, above the sink; looks like an air gap of some sort, but for what purpose?

Also, if I were to make an air gap with "discrete" components at least I'd make the top pipe go a bit lower into the "cone", to avoid risking throwing too much water around. Why is it made like this?

[image: the thing in the hotel bathroom]

Comment: If the drain pipe extended into the cone it wouldn't be an air gap, which requires that under no condition will the outlet be underwater.

Comment: My guess is that it's a condensate line from mechanical equipment, or maybe a drain for a ice maker.

Comment: Aaah right, so this explains why it's made like that.

Comment: This is not a home improvement question.

Comment: @AlaskaMan ... interesting though it is, I agree.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a home improvement question.

Comment: @AlaskaMan: yep I know it's a bit borderline, hence I did some research before asking: while this is not strictly a "home improvement" question, in the help center the "Questions you would typically ask a home contractor" bit was encouraging. Also, looking for "what's this thing" questions, I found many (some even about air gaps) similar to this, and they weren't closed as off-topic; the only difference is that this is in a hotel room, but changing only the framing it would have been like the others. That's why finally I decided to try to ask this, but if it get closed as OT I can understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least they used chrome, if the tube went into the drain there could be reverse migration if the drain was slow the separation is a requirement for food processing chillers to prevent back flow. This is probably a safety for a boiler or the piping.